# In Power Bi, how to create a DAX Measure based on if statement from different aggregations

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

I have a problem calculating the total in a matrix visualization using a measure with an if statement. I created this simplified model to ask this doubt.

The goal is to create a measure that:

- offers a 50% discount on books if customers bought more than 40% regarding the previous year and no discount otherwise
- offers a 20% discount on the other products (pens and pencils) if customers bought more than 30% regarding the previous year and no discount otherwise
- even if the above is fulfilled for some products, there will be no discount if in the sum of all the products the buyer didn't buy more than 10% compared to the previous year

I send the screen of the matrix summarizing what I should achieve:
[image]

Sample data:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14_aZz5wd2W6SdXZoWwTfPX_JXQUBh2k4?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Second case:
[image]

What could I add to the measure created to get "0" instead of "3000" in the register highlighted?

Comment: How many rows in your fact table?

Comment: There are 39 rows. I uploaded the fact table in Google Drive link of the post: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14_aZz5wd2W6SdXZoWwTfPX_JXQUBh2k4?usp=sharing

Comment: 39 in a dummy or in real table? I'm asking because if there are to many rows then it's important to have as light measure as possible. If you have few rows then it can be less code.

Comment: Ah sorry, it's a dummy table. The real table has 33.345 rows so far.

Comment: not a lot, I'll start with a solution, not sure for today, at least tomorrow.

Comment: you can mark it as answer or upvote or both on you decision if my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems works in a correct way. Please, note you have some wrong results in a result sample for example for `c-pen` `6500/5001-1=0.2997` it's less then 30. Also then `11501*0.2=2300.2` and you calculates `3450`. Also, the measure calculates for - as more then 40% for books and more then 20% for other, as you asks. So, if you will have `yoy = 0.4` then a discount is `0%` if `0.401` then `= 50%` for books. You can adjust the measure as `>=0.4` if you meant this.

```
Discount = 
VAR totalYOY = 
    CALCULATE(
        [sales_yoy_2]
        ,ALLSELECTED('base_2'[product])
    )
VAR allProductsWithinGroup =
        CALCULATETABLE(
            SUMMARIZE(
                'base_2'
                ,base_2[customer]
                ,base_2[product]
            )
            ,ALLSELECTED(base_2[product])
        )
VAR allProductsWithinGroupYOY =
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            allProductsWithinGroup
            ,"yoy",[sales_yoy_2]
            ,"salesTotal",[sales_total_2]
            ,"customerYOY", CALCULATE(
                                [sales_yoy_2]
                                ,ALLSELECTED('base_2'[product])
                            )
        )
VAR withDiscount = 
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            allProductsWithinGroupYOY
            ,"Discount", SWITCH(
                            TRUE()
                            ,[customerYOY]<0.1,0
                            ,[product]="book" && [yoy]>0.4,0.5*[salesTotal]
                            ,(NOT [product]="book") && [yoy]>0.3,0.2*[salesTotal]
                            ,0
                        )
        )
VAR result =
        FILTER(
            withDiscount
            ,[product] in VALUES(base_2[product])
        )
RETURN
    SUMX(result,[Discount])
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly! I have just one more doubt. Then I'm going to add a variable such as color. The problem is that later in that part it does not consider the correct discount in this new variable, how can I add it and make it mark the right value? I have edited the post with this new example and uploaded it to Drive